# Redux-Form onclick handler

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a redux-form and I want add a button that doesn't submit but elaborates fields to populate an other field. The problem is how to access fields values of the form in onclick handler?

I tried to resume them form store.getState but isn't so simple access to the state.

Make this with onSubmit handler is easy, but i need to reserve submit only for submit.

Help me!

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: You can use formValuesSelector() to get your formValues... Please refer redux form documentation ...https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/

Comment: Done as suggested! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this...

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'


class Test extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object,
  }
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {

    }
    this.getFormValues = this.getFormValues.bind(this)
  }

  getFormValues() {
    ////// at any function try this
    const { store } = this.context
    const state = store.getState()
    console.log(state.form.test.values)//you will get form values here
  }

  render() {
    return(<div>Redux Form Goes here</div>)
  }
}
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'test',  // a unique identifier for this form
  destroyOnUnmount: true,
})(Test)
```